# Recursion error when combining abstract factory pattern with delegator pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am learning about design patterns in Python and wanted to combine the abstract factory with the delegation pattern (to gain deeper insights into how the pattern works). However, I am getting a weird recursion error when combining the two patterns, which I do not understand.

The error is:

```
  [Previous line repeated 987 more times]
  File "c:\Users\jenny\Documents\design_pattern\creational\abstract_factory.py", line 60, in __getattribute__
    def __getattribute__(self, name: str):

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

It is raised when `client_with_laptop.display()` is called. However a/the recursion error is already stored in `client_with_laptop._hardware` during the `__init__`, although `factory.get_hardware()` returns a laptop instance.

The code is:

```
from abc import abstractmethod


class ITechnique:
    #abstract product

    @abstractmethod
    def display(self):
        pass

    def turn_on(self):
        print("I am on!")

    def turn_off(self):
        print("I am off!")


class Laptop(ITechnique):
    #concrete product
    def display(self):
        print("I'am a Laptop")

class Smartphone(ITechnique):
    #concrete product
    def display(self):
        print("I'am a Smartphone")

class Tablet(ITechnique):
    #concrete product
    def display(self):
        print("I'm a tablet!")


class IFactory:

    @abstractmethod
    def get_hardware():
        pass

class SmartphoneFactory(IFactory):

    def get_hardware(self):
        return Smartphone()


class LaptopFactory(IFactory):

    def get_hardware(self):
        return Laptop()

class TabletFactory(IFactory):

    def get_hardware(self):
        return Tablet()


class Client():

    def __init__(self, factory: IFactory) -> None:
        self._hardware = factory.get_hardware()

    def __getattribute__(self, name: str):
        return getattr(self._hardware, name)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    client_with_laptop = Client(LaptopFactory())
    client_with_laptop.display()

    client_with_tablet = Client(TabletFactory())
    client_with_tablet.display()

    client_with_smartphone = Client(SmartphoneFactory())
    client_with_smartphone.display()
```

When I access the attribute _hardware and remove the get_attribute section (so, basically, when I remove the delegation pattern), everything works as expected. See below the modified code section, which works:

```
class Client():

    def __init__(self, factory: IFactory) -> None:
        self._hardware = factory.get_hardware()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    client_with_laptop = Client(LaptopFactory())
    client_with_laptop._hardware.display()

    client_with_tablet = Client(TabletFactory())
    client_with_tablet._hardware.display()

    client_with_smartphone = Client(SmartphoneFactory())
    client_with_smartphone._hardware.display()
```

Can anybody help me explain why the recursion error occurs or how to fix it. My objective was (1) to have varying devices depending on the factory used in client and (2) to be able to call the methods from the `_hardware` without typing `client._hardware` all the time but calling it directly from the client object, e.g. `client.display()`. It is not whether this is, in reality, a useful approach or not; I simply want to understand the pattern - and the occurring error - better. :-)

Comment: I have an idea... but first what line is the recursion error complaining about?

Comment: The error is raised when the first time when I try to access `.display()`  from the client object. So its: `client_with_laptop.display()`. However, in my `client_with_laptop`, there is already a recursion-error. So it seems like something during the instantiation already does not work. I've updated my question with the missing information.

Comment: Why is display not @abstractmethod? Also I should have been more specific... The full stack trace I believe tries telling you in x in x in x... Is that the only place?

Comment: I simply forgot the decorator in `ITechnique` - I've added it, but it does not affect the error. When I am in debug-mode, I stop at the initialization of `self._hardware = factory.get_hardware()`. `factory.get_hardware()`returns a `Laptop` as expected, but `self._hardware` contains already the recursion error.

Comment: The traceback repeats the lines defined as the error code in my question.

Comment: Figured it out lol, it's funny really

Comment: One second, answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from abc import abstractmethod


class ITechnique:
    #abstract product

    @abstractmethod
    def display(self):
        pass

    def turn_on(self):
        print("I am on!")

    def turn_off(self):
        print("I am off!")


class Laptop(ITechnique):
    #concrete product
    def display(self):
        print("I'am a Laptop")

class Smartphone(ITechnique):
    #concrete product
    def display(self):
        print("I'am a Smartphone")

class Tablet(ITechnique):
    #concrete product
    def display(self):
        print("I'm a tablet!")


class IFactory:

    @abstractmethod
    def get_hardware():
        pass

class SmartphoneFactory(IFactory):

    def get_hardware(self):
        return Smartphone()


class LaptopFactory(IFactory):

    def get_hardware(self):
        return Laptop()

class TabletFactory(IFactory):

    def get_hardware(self):
        return Tablet()


class Client():

    def __init__(self, factory: IFactory) -> None:
        self._hardware = factory.get_hardware()

    def __getattribute__(self, name: str):
        return getattr(self._hardware, name)
```

After you created a Client object, that object has the
method *__getattribute__*. Inside this method you
then proceed to call this object's *__getattribute__*
method when you access this objects display method.
This causes instant recursion. To solve this you need
to [allow for figuring out what needs done](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__).
Read the documentation for *__getattr__* and *__getattribute__* to determine
how you want to handle it.

Comment: Yeah I have to modify `__get__attribute__` to `__get_attr__`. Actually, I'm not 100% sure what `__get_attribute__` does and where it's useful. Anyhow, this solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The recursion error occurs because the **getattribute** method in your Client class is triggering a recursive call when trying to access attributes of _hardware. This happens because **getattribute** calls getattr(self._hardware, name), which then tries to call **getattribute** again on the _hardware attribute, leading to infinite recursion.

To fix this, you can explicitly define which attributes should be delegated to the _hardware object by overriding the **getattr** method instead of **getattribute**. Here's how you can modify your Client class:

class Client:
def **init**(self, factory: IFactory) -> None:
self._hardware = factory.get_hardware()

```
def __getattr__(self, name: str):
    return getattr(self._hardware, name)
```